# Android failure to boot on LG

Tags: data-recovery, boot-loop, lg-thrill

I need to recover data from my AT&T LG Thrill Android Phone

Background:

My AT&T LG Thrill phone's battery died a couple of days ago because I forgot to charge it. When I charged the phone and tried to turn it on, it showed the LG logo followed by the dropping balls and the AT&T "Rethink Possible" screen. I then get a mesage that the Application Google Services Framework has crashed and the phone goes into a loop with the dropping balls showing again followed by "Rethink Possible" screen. This sequence repeats itself over and over and the phone does not get out of this loop.

I have been able to go into the recovery screen (both Safe Mode and the Android Recovery Service) and have cleared cache, etc. However, I DO NOT want to wipe user data and restore to factory settings as this will wipe all of my data (pictures, application data, etc).

Solution Needed:

I need a suggestion to a way of accessing my data so that I can back it up onto an SD card/computer. I DO NOT want to root the phone as this may void the warranty. What I'm looking for is a way of perhaps putting the original flash image on the micro SD card and then have the phone read that image. Or some other similar solution that will get the phone out of this loop and allow me to get to the data.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in recovery mode you should be able to use `adb` to get your data.

Answer (score -1):

There are two suggestions I have for you, both of which involve installing the Android SDK on your computer:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

This is sort of overkill for you, because there is a lot of things in there that you don't need, but the most important thing is `adb`. If you don't want the SDK lying around, you can install Virtualbox and install the SDK on a Linux VM.

Once you have `adb` installed, you can do:

1. Post the output of `adb logcat` online. This will give you some insight as to what is causing the crash.
2. Do:

`adb pull /sdcard`
`adb pull /data`

This will pull your data off of your phone and onto your computer. Once your stuff is safely off your phone, you can do whatever factory wiping you need to do.

Comment: Downvoted because these won't be mounted when the device is booting, and as the device cannot boot there is no way these will be mounted - also, the device may not be in USB Debugging mode.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to fix this issue without wiping it sorry, and as you cannot boot your device you cannot use the SDK to backup your data partition because:

1. It is the data that is most likely causing this issue
2. The data partition won't be mounted during boot time

Also, the above (or below) answer is assuming that you had USB Debugging enabled - did you?

Alas, you will have to wipe your device (including cache, dalvik-cache (if possible) and user data).